# How to make my div adjust it's height to the content when content elements change size?

Tags: html, css

So I have a div (`ipyplot-imgs-container-div-XQtySHZZdYxo9Q8nEKJ3qj`) acting as a container for images which can be clicked to enlarge.
The problem I'm facing is that when I click on an image to enlarge it, my div container height stays the same and makes me use scrollbar to see the enlarged image.
What would be the minimal change I need to perform in my `style` section to force that div to expand and adjust it's height to the enlarged image and then shrink back to it's original height when the enlarged image is closed? Not looking for general tips but rather a specific changes I need to make in my code snippet.

[Here's the same code snippet](https://codepen.io/karolzak/pen/XWKNVmE?editors=1000) as below hosted at codepen.io if anyone prefers that.

```html
            
<style>
  #ipyplot-imgs-container-div-XQtySHZZdYxo9Q8nEKJ3qj {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0%;
    overflow: auto;
    position: relative;
    overflow-y: scroll;
  }

  div.ipyplot-placeholder-div-XQtySHZZdYxo9Q8nEKJ3qj {
    width: 150px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 3px;
    position: relative;
  }

  div.ipyplot-content-div-XQtySHZZdYxo9Q8nEKJ3qj {
    width: 150px;
    background: white;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    border: 2px solid #ddd;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
  }

  div.ipyplot-content-div-XQtySHZZdYxo9Q8nEKJ3qj span.ipyplot-img-close {
    display: none;
  }

  div.ipyplot-content-div-XQtySHZZdYxo9Q8nEKJ3qj span {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
  }

  div.ipyplot-content-div-XQtySHZZdYxo9Q8nEKJ3qj img {
    width: 150px;
  }

  div.ipyplot-content-div-XQtySHZZdYxo9Q8nEKJ3qj span.ipyplot-img-close:hover {
    cursor: zoom-out;
  }
  div.ipyplot-content-div-XQtySHZZdYxo9Q8nEKJ3qj span.ipyplot-img-expand:hover {
    cursor: zoom-in;
  }

  div[id^=ipyplot-content-div-XQtySHZZdYxo9Q8nEKJ3qj]:target {
    transform: scale(2.5);
    transform-origin: left top;
    z-index: 5000;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
  }

  div[id^=ipyplot-content-div-XQtySHZZdYxo9Q8nEKJ3qj]:target span.ipyplot-img-close {
    display: block;
  }

  div[id^=ipyplot-content-div-XQtySHZZdYxo9Q8nEKJ3qj]:target span.ipyplot-img-expand {
    display: none;
  }
</style>
<div id="ipyplot-imgs-container-div-XQtySHZZdYxo9Q8nEKJ3qj">
  <div class="ipyplot-placeholder-div-XQtySHZZdYxo9Q8nEKJ3qj">
    <div id="ipyplot-content-div-XQtySHZZdYxo9Q8nEKJ3qj-hs2AVawQHtWqavC72jS4xY" class="ipyplot-content-div-XQtySHZZdYxo9Q8nEKJ3qj">
      <h4 style="font-size: 12px; word-wrap: break-word;">0</h4>
      <h4 style="font-size: 9px; margin-left: 5px; margin-right: 5px; word-wrap: break-word; white-space: normal;">https://raw.githubusercontent.com/karolzak/boxdetect/master/images/checkbox-example.jpg</h4>
      <img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/karolzak/boxdetect/master/images/checkbox-example.jpg"/>
      <a href="#!">
        <span class="ipyplot-img-close"></span>
      </a>
      <a href="#ipyplot-content-div-XQtySHZZdYxo9Q8nEKJ3qj-hs2AVawQHtWqavC72jS4xY">
        <span class="ipyplot-img-expand"></span>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="ipyplot-placeholder-div-XQtySHZZdYxo9Q8nEKJ3qj">
    <div id="ipyplot-content-div-XQtySHZZdYxo9Q8nEKJ3qj-WrKnPdHkgL6KFStYtmZxqv" class="ipyplot-content-div-XQtySHZZdYxo9Q8nEKJ3qj">
      <h4 style="font-size: 12px; word-wrap: break-word;">1</h4>
      <h4 style="font-size: 9px; margin-left: 5px; margin-right: 5px; word-wrap: break-word; white-space: normal;">https://raw.githubusercontent.com/karolzak/boxdetect/master/images/checkboxes-details.jpg</h4>
      <img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/karolzak/boxdetect/master/images/checkboxes-details.jpg"/>
      <a href="#!">
        <span class="ipyplot-img-close"></span>
      </a>
      <a href="#ipyplot-content-div-XQtySHZZdYxo9Q8nEKJ3qj-WrKnPdHkgL6KFStYtmZxqv">
        <span class="ipyplot-img-expand"></span>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="ipyplot-placeholder-div-XQtySHZZdYxo9Q8nEKJ3qj">
    <div id="ipyplot-content-div-XQtySHZZdYxo9Q8nEKJ3qj-4uDKbReLnpAnKLN5iHNrfR" class="ipyplot-content-div-XQtySHZZdYxo9Q8nEKJ3qj">
      <h4 style="font-size: 12px; word-wrap: break-word;">2</h4>
      <h4 style="font-size: 9px; margin-left: 5px; margin-right: 5px; word-wrap: break-word; white-space: normal;">https://raw.githubusercontent.com/karolzak/boxdetect/master/images/example1.png</h4>
      <img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/karolzak/boxdetect/master/images/example1.png"/>
      <a href="#!">
        <span class="ipyplot-img-close"></span>
      </a>
      <a href="#ipyplot-content-div-XQtySHZZdYxo9Q8nEKJ3qj-4uDKbReLnpAnKLN5iHNrfR">
        <span class="ipyplot-img-expand"></span>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `overflow-y` property and set `height: 100vh` instead of `100%` in   `#ipyplot-imgs-container-div-XQtySHZZdYxo9Q8nEKJ3qj`. I hope your problem will be fixed.

```
  #ipyplot-imgs-container-div-XQtySHZZdYxo9Q8nEKJ3qj {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    margin: 0%;
    overflow: auto;
    position: relative;
  }
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer but that's not quite what I am looking for. With this approach my div now takes up the entire available space rather than just adjusting to my contents size